# Python Scikit learn script crashing in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have a python script using Scikit-learn libraries and it works completely fine when I run it manually in either Jupyter notebook or command line. However, it doesn't work when I schedule it in Windows Task Scheduler. After spending a lot of time I realised the issue is due to the `sklearn` imports. If I comment out the sklearn imports, the script works fine in the scheduler but the moment I include a sklearn import, the scheduler doesn't execute one line of the script. I have no idea what is causing this and it's even more surprising that the script works like a charm when running it manually. I've uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda distribution on my PC but no result. Any help on how I can fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to fix this. Turns out it's a corrupted `scipy` package. Uninstalling and re-installing it fixed the issue.

The way I figured it out is by running my python script as a batch file which threw the following error

> from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I never got this error when I ran my python script from the windows scheduler or Jupyter notebook or even command line, which is very strange.